# Check if compiling with MATLAB mex

Tags: c++, c, matlab, mex

I want to make a cross-platform function that has extra functionalities if compiled under MATLAB.
Is there a define that can give me that information?

In other words, I'm implementing it as follows:

```
void f(void) {
    if (x) {
        (...)
    }
#ifdef MATLAB
    do_other_stuff();
#endif
}
```

and I need to have something replacing

```
#ifdef MATLAB
```

to verify that it is being compiled under matlab as a MEX function.

My '>> mex -v' outputs this:

```
'>> mex -v
-> mexopts.sh sourced from directory (DIR = $HOME/.matlab/$REL_VERSION)    
   FILE = /home/bmmo/.matlab/R2009b/mexopts.sh
----------------------------------------------------------------
->    MATLAB                = /usr/matlab2009b
->    CC                    = gcc
->    CC flags:
         CFLAGS             = -ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE  -fexceptions -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread
         CDEBUGFLAGS        = -g
         COPTIMFLAGS        = -O -DNDEBUG
         CLIBS              = -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/matlab2009b/bin/glnxa64 -L/usr/matlab2009b/bin/glnxa64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm -lstdc++
         arguments          =  -DMX_COMPAT_32
->    CXX                   = g++
->    CXX flags:
         CXXFLAGS           = -ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread
         CXXDEBUGFLAGS      = -g
         CXXOPTIMFLAGS      = -O -DNDEBUG
         CXXLIBS            = -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/matlab2009b/bin/glnxa64 -L/usr/matlab2009b/bin/glnxa64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm
         arguments          =  -DMX_COMPAT_32
->    FC                    = g95
->    FC flags:
         FFLAGS             = -fexceptions -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer
         FDEBUGFLAGS        = -g
         FOPTIMFLAGS        = -O
         FLIBS              = -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/matlab2009b/bin/glnxa64 -L/usr/matlab2009b/bin/glnxa64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm
         arguments          =  -DMX_COMPAT_32
->    LD                    = gcc
->    Link flags:
         LDFLAGS            = -pthread -shared -Wl,--version-script,/usr/matlab2009b/extern/lib/glnxa64/mexFunction.map -Wl,--no-undefined
         LDDEBUGFLAGS       = -g
         LDOPTIMFLAGS       = -O
         LDEXTENSION        = .mexa64
         arguments          = 
->    LDCXX                 = 
->    Link flags:
         LDCXXFLAGS         = 
         LDCXXDEBUGFLAGS    = 
         LDCXXOPTIMFLAGS    = 
         LDCXXEXTENSION     = 
         arguments          = 
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Try running

```
>> mex -v
```

in your Matlab and inspect the `COMPFLAGS` it lists.

On my machine I see `/DMATLAB_MEX_FILE` that is a const `MATLAB_MEX_FILE` is being defined. I guess this is the case for other platforms, but its worth checking in advance.

Comment: This is what I use when I am compiling a library I'm developing with multiple possible compilers. +1.

Comment: Well, in my case the define isn't there. I'm in Linux 64bits, Matlab R2009b. But I've seen your solution around and apparently it works for other people

Comment: @manatttta have you configured your mex compiler by running `>> mex -setup`? Can you post the output of running `>> mex -v` ?

Comment: @manatttta - You can also check your `mexopts.sh` shell file by navigating to the `bin/mex/` folder inside the MATLAB application directory.  In the file, navigate to where the Linux case is, and read off what the `COMPFLAGS` variable says.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I'm posting my output.

Comment: @rayryeng I've checked out that file and it has no reference to that define

Comment: it seems like you have `MX_COMPAT_32` defined. it's a bit strange

Comment: @manatttta how did you configured your `mex`? what were the options in `>> mex -setup` and what did you choose?

Comment: @Shai I only configured 'mexopts.sh'to remove the -ansi definition